# Regex: Select text/string between symbols that contains another symbol (tags that contains specific string)

Tags: windows-10, notepad++, regex

I want to select all text between `=>`  and  `=>` only if contains `[` or `]`

> I love you `=> predici-video [date] =>` between myself and her.

so, only this `=> predici-video [date] =>`

Comment: This smells so badly of an XY problem...
I'm sure if you post the actual source, and what you're trying to do, there're better ways than a single RegEx... maybe mutliple RegEx instead... so it is easier to read.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Search for : `=>.*(\[|\]).*=>`

Explanation:

- `.*` - zero or more characters
- `(one|two)` - one or the other
- `\[` - the character `[` escaped.

Screenshot from notepad++:

---

[image]

Answer (score 4):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<==>)[^=>]*[][][^=>]*(?==>)`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Find All in Current Document</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<==>)     # positive lookbehind, make sure we have => before
[^=>]*      # 0 or more any character that is not = or >
[][]        # character class, matches [ or ]
[^=>]*      # 0 or more any character that is not = or >
(?==>)      # positive lookahead, make sure we have => after
```

**If you want to catch also `=>`, use: `=>[^=>]*[][][^=>]*=>`**

---

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Comment: hello @Toto, can you make the second case, to select also the `=>` before and after those words ?

Comment: @JustMe: I've already put a comment in bold in the answer, just after explanation. Be aware that the other answer doesn't work if you have multiple text to catch in a single line.